# Is the dictionary inside protected method thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I have an abstract class which has a Protected Method. I am using dictionary inside this method. And this class has 2 implementations. Both the classes call this protected method for 
some operations. If both the implementations are running in different threads, is the dictionary inside the protected method thread safe?

Protected method is as below

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> GenerateParameterFromQueue()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters;
        string queueInput = this._Queue.QueueInput;
        string[] inputArray = Regex.Split(queueInput,Constants.KEY_DELIMITER); 

        parameters = inputArray.ToDictionary(s => s.Split(Convert.ToChar(Constants.KEY_EQUALITY))[0], s => s.Split(Convert.ToChar(Constants.KEY_EQUALITY))[1]);

        return parameters;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since the dictionary in the method is created per thread inside the method itself, your use of the `Dictionary` is thread safe. Of course, that does not mean that any use of it outside the method after it has been returned is automatically thread safe.

It's only if two threads access/change a single `Dictionary` that you will have a problem. It has nothing to do with the method being protected.

The thing I'd worry about in the method is the this._Queue variable though, since it's shared between multiple threads and you're not locking it, you need to make sure that it's thread safe in itself.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Joachim. Regarding this._Queue, it is not a static variable. And I am setting it in other method as below     public void ProcessQueue(Queue queue){this._Queue = queue;} I guess this will create new _Queue object per thread, and hence it is tread safe. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It would greatly depend on parts of the system's design that aren't shown in your question. Could multiple threads be running in the same object at the same time? If so, not necessarily thread safe since the threads would by design use the same _Queue reference. Could the same Queue be passed into multiple objects? Same thing there, not necessarily thread safe since several objects' _Queue variable may refer to the same Queue. Keeping one thread inside one object instance, staying away from statics and making sure not to pass shared objects to multiple instances will generally keep you safe.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is "thread-safe" but not because it's a protected method. It's thread safe because you are generating the dictionary from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The `protected` keyword only means that that method is only visible within containing types or subclasses. It *does not* make it thread safe. The `Dictionary` is being created for each thread call to the method, this makes the `Dictionary` thread safe in this example...

For thread safe collections see the [ConcurrentCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) classes.

I hope this helps.